# What is an eloquent way to sort an array of hashes based on whether a key is empty in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

```
array = [{ name:'Joe', foo:'bar' },
         { name:'Bob', foo:''    },
         { name:'Hal', foo:'baz' }
        ]
```

What is an eloquent way to sort so that if foo is empty, then put it at the end, and not change the order of the other elements?

Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array.partition { |h| !h[:foo].empty? }.flatten
```

Comment: While this _works_ in current implementations, one should note that the documented contract around [`Enumerable#partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) makes no promises about the internal ordering of its two result arrays. I can imagine a future implementation of Enumerable exploiting automatic parallelism producing results differently ordered than the input.

Comment: @dbenhur - Thank you. That is important because I am sorting by another key first. But how to ensure that the two result arrays' internal order does not change?

Comment: You'd have to sort the resulting arrays if you were worried about `partition` not returning them in their original order. But if you're worried about such things, you should look on all `Array` and `Enumerable` methods with a jaundiced eye. That's a bit more future-proofing than I care to do.

Comment: @BSeven see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14847486/1074296) using `sort_by` for how to do this with ordering assured.

Comment: @zetetic I do look with a jaundiced eye. If ordering is significant it's better to be explicit than accidental. Do you also rely on SQL `SELECT ... FROM ...` producing a consistent a reproducible order without `ORDER BY`?  If so, you better avoid concurrent implementations with "follow the leader" optimization. Knowing your contracts is just good programming.

Comment: @dbenhur it's a valid concern, to be sure. I wouldn't expect a SQL query to return an ordered result set. But a Ruby Array is "an ordered, integer-indexed collection" according to the docs. I would be surprised to find operations on an ordered collection that did not preserve the order--that would be poor design. Do you sort the result of `Array#collect`?

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [
  { name:'Joe', foo:'bar' },
  { name:'Bob', foo:''    },
  { name:'Hal', foo:'baz' }
]

arraydup = array.dup
array.delete_if{ |h| h[:foo].empty? }
array += (arraydup - array)
```

Which results in:

```
[
    [0] {
        :name => "Joe",
        :foo => "bar"
    },
    [1] {
        :name => "Hal",
        :foo => "baz"
    },
    [2] {
        :name => "Bob",
        :foo => ""
    }
]
```

With a little refactoring:

```
array += ((array.dup) - array.delete_if{ |h| h[:foo].empty? })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.find_all{|elem| !elem[:foo].empty?} + array.find_all{|elem| elem[:foo].empty?}
```

returns

```
[{:name=>"Joe", :foo=>"bar"}, {:name=>"Hal", :foo=>"baz"}, {:name=>"Bob", :foo=>""}]
```

Answer (score 1):

One can produce keys as tuples, where the first part indicates null/not-null, and the second part is the original index, then sort_by [nulls_last, original_index].

```
def sort_nulls_last_preserving_original_order array 
  array.map.with_index.
    sort_by { |h,i| [ (h[:foo].empty? ? 1 : 0), i ] }.
    map(&:first)
end
```

Note this avoids all the gross array mutation of some of the other answers and is constructed from pure functional transforms.

Answer (score 0):

```
array.each_with_index do |item, index|
  array << (array.delete_at(index)) if item[:foo].blank?
end
```

Use whatever you have in place of `blank?`.

Comment: You should never alter an element you are looping on.

Comment: I don't think that's true (or at least not stated precisely enough). You alter elements in loops all the time. I would agree that it's dangerous to change the size of an enumerable during iteration. Upon further reflection, the method here would ultimately not work, as it would skip over elements that move forward in the index as other elements are pushed to the back.